# AttributeError at /

Tags: python, django

'int' object has no attribute 'update'

Hello! I have this error, why is it prduce? If you could help me please

views.py:

```
def Completar(request, id_especialidad):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    especialidad = Especialidad.objects.get(id=id_especialidad)
    pedido =    Pedido.objects.filter(especialidad=especialidad).update(cantidad=0).update(estado="").update(fecha_pedido="").update(fecha_entrega="")
    articulo = Articulo.objects.all()
    especialidad.estadistica = 0
    especialidad.estado = ""
    especialidad.save()
    articulo.total_pedido = 0
    articulo.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/home/')
```

models.py:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    especialidad   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    fecha_entrega  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    fecha_pedido   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad       = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    estado         = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='pendiente')
```

Comment: You can't chain `update()` calls as the [`update()` method is applied instantly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update). Pass all of the fields to first `update()` call itself.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This more an answer than a comment, isn't it?